# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

Tags: jquery, oracle, oracle11g

I use this SQL query to insert value into Oracle:

```
INSERT INTO SESSIONS (
  SESSIONID,
  TYPE,
  ACTIVITY_START,
  ACTIVITY_END,
  ACTIVITY,
  USERNAME,
  IP_ADDRESS,
  LOGIN_TIME,
  LOGOUT_TIME)
select SESSION_ID_SEQ.nextval, null, null, null, ?, ?, ?, sysdate, null
FROM SESSIONS
having COUNT(*) < 50
```

This is the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE SESSIONS(
  SESSIONID VARCHAR2(30 ) NOT NULL,
  TYPE VARCHAR2(30 ),
  ACTIVITY_START DATE,
  ACTIVITY_END DATE,
  ACTIVITY CLOB,
  USERNAME VARCHAR2(30 ),
  IP_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(30 ),
  LOGIN_TIME DATE,
  LOGOUT_TIME DATE
)
/

CREATE SEQUENCE SESSION_ID_SEQ
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999
 NOMINVALUE
 CACHE 20
/
```

I use sequence to generate unique ID for every new session record.
But I get error when I run the code:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
```

Can you help me to fix the problem?

Comment: ur insert query is wrong.what u r trying to do?

Comment: Can you show me how to fix the Insert SQL?

Comment: what u r trying to do, could u plz tell us?

Comment: I wan to insert record into table SESSIONS using sequence for generating SESSIONID. But I want to insert record only if the records are below 50 rows.

Comment: **if the records are below 50 rows** this part still unclear for me.by the way why SESSIONID is varchar2(30)?

Comment: My mistake - it should be integer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88282/discussion-between-pitchers-and-peter-penzov).

Comment: There are many situations in which you can't use a sequence. There's a good list [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287). Aggregate queries aren't mentioned specifically, but `GROUP BY` is. Try the query without the `HAVING` to see if that's causing the trouble. And you'll need to work out the `HAVING` part anyway because it doesn't make a lot of sense without a `GROUP BY` - maybe use `WHERE ROWNUM < 50` instead?

Comment: @EdGibbs Well the general purpose of the query is to insert rows if the limit is not reached(in this cases 50). Is there any other way to get the same result?

Comment: @PeterPenzov do you mean if the total row count of the table is less than 50?

Comment: And if the row count is less than 50 do you want to get it up to 50? For example, if the table has 20 rows do you want to insert 30 rows?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to insert rows to get the `SESSIONS` table row count up to 50, what you need here is to count 50 minus the number of rows in `SESSIONS`. To count you can use a hack of the Oracle `CONNECT BY`, which is mostly associated with hierarchical queries but has a lot of other uses. For example, try this query, which will return 50 rows numbered 1 through 50:

```
SELECT ROWNUM
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 50;
```

This query will return 20 rows if your `SESSION` table already has 30 rows in it:

```
SELECT ROWNUM
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 50 - (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SESSIONS
);
```

BTW, while your query will need `ROWNUM` for the `CONNECT BY` it doesn't doesn't need it as a `SELECT` value; that was just for demonstration purposes.

As I understand it, your query would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO SESSIONS (
  SESSIONID,
  TYPE,
  ACTIVITY_START,
  ACTIVITY_END,
  ACTIVITY,
  USERNAME,
  IP_ADDRESS,
  LOGIN_TIME,
  LOGOUT_TIME)
select SESSION_ID_SEQ.nextval, null, null, null, ?, ?, ?, sysdate, null
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 50 - (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM SESSIONS
);
```

Since four of the columns will be null (and because none of the four columns defines a `DEFAULT` value that you're overriding with null), you can shorten the query by omitting the columns:

```
INSERT INTO SESSIONS (
  SESSIONID,
  ACTIVITY,
  USERNAME,
  IP_ADDRESS,
  LOGIN_TIME)
select SESSION_ID_SEQ.nextval, ?, ?, ?, sysdate
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 50 - (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM SESSIONS
);
```

Finally, note that the `SYSDATE` value will be exactly the same for every row you insert. That's because `SYSDATE` (and `SYSTIMESTAMP` for that matter) is evaluated only once for each query, and the same value is used for the duration of the query. Even if your query ran for an hour, each row would have the same `SYSDATE`.